# Nnumber of HTML redirects from cURL

Tags: bash, shell-script, curl

My little script extracts DOI's from a csv files in order to check whether they are right. The number should equal `3`, and if it doesn't, I want to output an message.

```
#!/bin/bash

doi=j.1540-6261.2011.01681.x
num_redirect=[[ curl -L -s -w %{num_redirects} "http://dx.doi.org/"$doi -o /dev/null ]]

echo $num_redirect

if (( "$num_redirect" -eq 3 ))
then
  echo $doi " is correct"
else
  echo $doi " is wrong"
fi
```

Although `num_redirects` appears to be `3` in my terminal, I keep getting the error `((: -lt 3 : syntax error in expression (error token is "3 ")` and also a wrong output.

Then I checked whether `num_redirect` is actually an integer with

```
case $num_redirect in
   ''|*[!0-9]*) echo bad ;;
   *) echo good ;;
esac
```

(https://stackoverflow.com/a/3951175/3621464) and I receive `bad`.

Now I wonder what kind of output `curl -s -w %{num_redirects}` is. `echo ${#num_redirect}` says it's of `0` length.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `curl` command is executed but its output is not assigned to `num_redirect`. This means that the output of curl is shown, i.e. "3" (without a newline). However, a newline is inserted when `echo $num_redirect` is run, as the variable is empty. This gives you the impression that the variable `num_redirect` has the value of "3".

You should either use backticks or `$()` to execute a command and capture its output on stdout.

```
num_redirect=$(curl -L -s -w %{num_redirects} "http://dx.doi.org/"$doi -o /dev/null)
```

Also, you should compare the variable to an integer by using `[` and `]`. Now you are, again, just evaluating the command.

```
if [ "$num_redirect" -eq 3 ]
then
    ...
else
    ...
fi
```